# How to I disable UI Wizard while updating my WPF application to new versions?

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-installer

Hello I have a WPF I am using windows installer (classic setup project template in Visual Studio 2015) to deploy that app.Now while updating I am using `RemovePreviousVersions` project property.

For updating I am downloading new setup.exe file and running it to update my WPF app. But for second time a also it showing UI wizard to select Install Path ..etc.

How to I disable UI Wizard while updating my WPF application?

Comment: I am not familiar with the options available for the VS2015 Installer, but you will need to set conditions on the dialog pages so that it is skipped. I am not certain that VS2015 exposes this ability. This would mean that you will need a full version of InstallShield to modify dialogs and and their default behavior.

Answer (score 1):

You're just installing an MSI file, so the standard msiexec command line options can be used. Use:

msiexec /I [path to msi file] /q

with any of the other options you may need. It's the /q that makes it quiet.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa367988(v=vs.85).aspx